# Using at least in SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have been working on my SQL work for the following. I am able to write a query for the following using "AND" but i am able to come up with using "at least" in query.

**Find the sids of suppliers who supply a red part and a green part.**

```
Select s.sid from suppliers s, catalog c, parts p
where s.sid=c.sid and c.pid=p.pid and p.color='Red'
intersect
Select s.sid from suppliers s, catalog c, parts p
where s.sid=c.sid and c.pid=p.pid and p.color='Green';
```

How to write a query using `atleast` for the question like

**"Find the sids of suppliers who supply at least two red parts and at least two green parts."**

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally avoid a query that uses a subselect like in the first reply.  Here's a solution that uses one query with a GROUP BY and HAVING clause.  You just count up the red and greens and filter in the HAVING by the suppliers that have the stats you want.  Notice that joining to the suppliers table is unnecessary.

```
SELECT
  c.sid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.color='Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS redCt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.color='Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS greenCt
FROM
catalog c
JOIN parts p ON c.pid = p.pid
GROUP BY c.sid
HAVING redCt >= 2 AND greenCt >= 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85e8c1/14

Comment: The reason I avoided this is because it is not portable. The query will fail in MS SQL for instance.

Comment: True, although he did tag it as MySQL.

Comment: Agreed. Just explaining the rationale behind my answer in case a similar issue arises with another DBMS :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sid from
(select 
 s.sid sid, 
 sum(case when p.color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as red, 
 sum(case when p.color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) as green
 from suppliers s
 left join catalog c on s.sid = c.sid
 left join parts p on p.pid = c.pid
 group by s.sid) s
where 
green >= 2 and red >= 2
```

The idea is to build up the list of suppliers with counts of how many red and green parts they supply, and then filtering by the threshold values.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85e8c1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> SELECT * FROM
>   (
>      Select s.sid ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY p.color ORDER BY  s.sid DESC )ROWNUM from suppliers s
>      inner join  catalog c on s.sid=c.sid 
>      INNER JOIN parts p
>      ON c.pid=p.pid where p.color='Red' or p.color='Green'
>   )T4
>   WHERE ROWNUM>=2